# Textarea validation

Tags: php, html

When using input type text, I validate using the following code.

```
<input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php echo $form->value("subject"); ?>">
<?php echo $form->error("subject"); ?>
<textarea name="body" cols="10" rows="10"></textarea>
<?php echo $form->error("body"); ?>
```

As you can see, I am also using a textarea.

How would I add the `value="<?php echo $form->value("body"); ?>"` to the textarea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in between the `<textarea>` tags.

```
<textarea name="body" cols="10" rows="10"><?php echo $form->value("body"); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it within the  tag itself, but that's not about validation so are you asking something else?

```
<textarea name="body" cols="10" rows="10"><?php echo $form->value("body"); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't perfect, that is just the code that fires the error back (validation). Thanks.

Comment: @Luke, okay great. Looks like you are all set.

Comment: Always difficult when two people answer the same thing, I usually go with the oldest answer if it's correct.

Comment: @Luke - yep - fair is fair, he was first by the timestamp by a wide margin. Serves me right for being slow!